# Beginner problems with references to arrays in python 3.1.1

Tags: python

As part of the last assignment in a beginner python programing class, I have been assigned a traveling sales man problem. I settled on a recursive function to find each permutation and the sum of the distances between the destinations, however, I am have a lot of problems with references. Arrays in different instances of the Permute and Main functions of TSP seem to be pointing to the same reference.

```
from math import sqrt
    class TSP:
        def __init__(self):
            self.CartisianCoordinates = [['A',[1,1]], ['B',[2,2]], ['C',[2,1]], ['D',[1,2]], ['E',[3,3]]]
            self.Array = []
            self.Max = 0
            self.StoredList = ['',0]
        def Distance(self, i1, i2):
            x1 = self.CartisianCoordinates[i1][1][0]
            y1 = self.CartisianCoordinates[i1][1][1]
            x2 = self.CartisianCoordinates[i2][1][0]
            y2 = self.CartisianCoordinates[i2][1][1]
            return sqrt(pow((x2 - x1), 2) + pow((y2 - y1), 2))

    def Evaluate(self):
        temparray = []
        Data = []
        for i in range(len(self.CartisianCoordinates)):
            Data.append([])
        for i1 in range(len(self.CartisianCoordinates)):
            for i2 in range(len(self.CartisianCoordinates)):
                if i1 != i2:
                    temparray.append(self.Distance(i1, i2))
                else:
                    temparray.append('X')
            Data[i1] = temparray
            temparray = []
        self.Array = Data
        self.Max = len(Data)
    def Permute(self,varray,index,vcarry,mcarry): #Problem Class
        array = varray[:]
        carry = vcarry[:]
        for i in range(self.Max):
            print ('ARRAY:', array)
            print (index,i,carry,array[index][i])
            if array[index][i] != 'X':
                carry[0] += self.CartisianCoordinates[i][0]
                carry[1] += array[index][i]
                if len(carry) != self.Max:
                    temparray = array[:]
                    for j in range(self.Max):temparray[j][i] = 'X'
                    index = i
                    mcarry += self.Permute(temparray,index,carry,mcarry)
                else:
                    return mcarry
        print ('pass',mcarry)
        return mcarry
    def Main(self):
        out = []
        self.Evaluate()
        for i in range(self.Max):
            array = self.Array[:] #array appears to maintain the same reference after each copy, resulting in an incorrect array being passed to Permute after the first iteration.
            print (self.Array[:])
            for j in range(self.Max):array[j][i] = 'X'
            print('I:', i, array)
            out.append(self.Permute(array,i,[str(self.CartisianCoordinates[i][0]),0],[]))
        return out


SalesPerson = TSP()
print(SalesPerson.Main())
```

It would be greatly appreciated if you could provide me with help in solving the reference problems I am having. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Slicing a list (by using `[:]` as you do) does not create a deep copy -- it creates a shallow copy.  That means that if the list contains references to other lists, the copy will contain the same *references* -- not references to *new lists*.  Put another way, only the list itself is copied, not its elements or its elements' elements.

What you want here is a *deep copy*.  Instead of

```
array = self.Array[:]
```

try

```
array = copy.deepcopy(self.Array)
```

for which you'll need `import copy`.